# Admin login fails in a multi node wso2 api manager setup when the second node comes up

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a 3-node WSO2 API Manager setup. There is an external load balancer in place.
When I bring up a first instance, everything loads fine and there are no errors in wso2carbon.log. In addition I am able to login as 'admin' using the password configured in user-mgt.xml

When I now bring up the second node, and retry the above process, I am unable to login. The page doesn't even give me a 403 or auth error.

I have the Hazelcast members added with 'wka' option in axis2.xml
I have configured the xmls under jaggeryapps as well.
I have the DBs initialized as well. The service cones up without errors in the logs as well.

Comment: "I have a 3-node WSO2 API Manager setup" - is this an All-In-One deployment, or have you distributed the components in your deployment?

Comment: @MiddlewareManiac - Chamila answered the question below. I marked it as accepted answer. For the sake of posterity, it is a 3xAll-in-one instances (API manager, store, publisher, carbon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up sticky session in your load balancer.